# Jquery example not working (tested on IE,CHROME and FIREFOX)

Tags: jquery, html

I`ve been trying to make this example work, but with no success at all (using vs2010):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #algo
        {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            color: White;
            background-color: Red;
            border: 4px solid black;
            margin: 100px 0px 0px 80px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#algo').animate({ 'margin-top': '300px', 'margin-left': '400px' }, 1000);
        }); </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="algo">
        <p>
            lol</p>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried with the minified version as well but it's still not working...is there anything i'm missing?

Comment: Inside the document.ready, run an alert `alert("jquery loaded");`. Any result?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any jQuery import here.

Comment: I forgot to put the jquery import, but when i tried to do this example before, even with the import, it wasn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pull out the src=jquery.js reference and add a link to jquery above it like so:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
//then do what ever you intend to do
            }); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing JQuery reference.. Try like below it will help you...

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#algo').animate({ 'margin-top': '300px', 'margin-left': '400px' }, 1000);
    }); 
    </script>
```